# How to join/merge/concat an filled dataframe with an empty dataframe by index and columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**Example:**

```
   df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,0,0,0,0,0],
                'b':[0,0,0,0,0,0], 'b':[0,0,0,0,0,0]}, index=list('abcdef'))

print (df1)


       a  b  c
    a  0  0  0
    b  0  0  0
    c  0  0  0
    d  0  0  0
    e  0  0  0
    f  0  0  0

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a':range(4),
                'b':[5,6,7,8]}, index=list('abce'))

print (df2)

   a  b
a  0  5
b  1  6
c  2  7
e  3  8
```

How do I combine the filled dataframe into the empty one that will looks like this?

```
   a  b c
a  0  5 0
b  1  6 0
c  2  7 0
d  0  0 0
e  3  8 0
f  0  0 0
```

The problem is that it isn't fit for index **and** column.

Comment: Maybe this question is related to Stackoverflow more than here.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is the most efficient way, but it works:

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', left_index=True, right_index=True, suffixes=('_x', ''))
df3['a'].fillna(df3['a_x'], inplace=True)
df3['b'].fillna(df3['b_x'], inplace=True)
df3.drop(['a_x', 'b_x'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```