# How to merge/join empty dataframe with another filled dataframe by equal indices and column names?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I want to combine two `dataframes`. One `dataframe`, let's say `Empty_DF`, is empty and has big size (320 columns by 240 rows) with indexes and column names just integers. The other one,`ROI_DF`, is smaller and filled and matches at a certain location the indexes and column names.

I have tried to use the `pandas.merge` function as it was suggested in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55506423/how-to-join-merge-concat-an-filled-dataframe-with-an-empty-dataframe-by-index-an); however, it would just append the columns to the empty `dataframe` `Empty_DF` and not replacing the values.

```
Empty_DF = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,0,0,0,0,0],
            'b':[0,0,0,0,0,0], 'b':[0,0,0,0,0,0]}, index=list('abcdef'))

print (Empty_DF)

 ROI_DF= pd.DataFrame({'a':range(4),
            'b':[5,6,7,8]}, index=list('abce'))

 print(ROI_DF)
   a  b  c
a  0  0  0
b  0  0  0
c  0  0  0
d  0  0  0
e  0  0  0
f  0  0  0
```

In this example, it is sufficient since the `dataframe` is small and the `pandas.fillna` option with pandas.drop can be used. Is there a more efficient way of optimizing this to bigger `dataframes`?

```
df3 = pd.merge(Empty_DF, ROI_DF, how='left', left_index=True, 
right_index=True, suffixes=('_x', ''))
df3['a'].fillna(df3['a_x'], inplace=True)
df3['b'].fillna(df3['b_x'], inplace=True)
df3.drop(['a_x', 'b_x'], axis=1, inplace=True)

print(df3)
 a  b c
a  0  5 0
b  1  6 0
c  2  7 0
d  0  0 0
e  3  8 0
f  0  0 0
```

Answer (score 3):

This is perfect case for [`DataFrame.update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html), which aligns on indices

```
Empty_DF.update(ROI_DF)
```

**Output**

```
print(df3)

     a    b  c
a  0.0  5.0  0
b  1.0  6.0  0
c  2.0  7.0  0
d  0.0  0.0  0
e  3.0  8.0  0
f  0.0  0.0  0
```

---

Note that `update` is in place, as quoted from the documentation:

> Modify in place using non-NA values from another DataFrame.

That means that your original dataframe will be updated by the new values. To prevent this, use:

```
df3 = Empty_DF.copy()
df3.update(ROI_DF)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can either use `update`:

```
Empty_DF.update(ROI_DF)
```

output:

```
     a    b  c
a  0.0  5.0  0
b  1.0  6.0  0
c  2.0  7.0  0
d  0.0  0.0  0
e  3.0  8.0  0
f  0.0  0.0  0
```

Or `loc`:

```
Empty_DF.loc[ROI_DF.index, ROI_DF.columns] = ROI_DF
```

output:

```
   a  b  c
a  0  5  0
b  1  6  0
c  2  7  0
d  0  0  0
e  3  8  0
f  0  0  0
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case `reindex_like`

```
yourdf=ROI_DF.reindex_like(Empty_DF).fillna(0)
     a    b    c
a  0.0  5.0  0.0
b  1.0  6.0  0.0
c  2.0  7.0  0.0
d  0.0  0.0  0.0
e  3.0  8.0  0.0
f  0.0  0.0  0.0
```